# JUnit Best Practice for Suites?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

So I am combining my unit tests into suites. I was told if I could categorize the tests..

So I have the following tests that would be categorized for the

```
LoginSuite
- loginTest.java
- registerUser.java
- forgotPass.java
```

Then I have another suite called MessagesSuite with the following unit tests in it

```
MessageSuite
- searchMessages.java
- sendDirectMessage.java
- sendChannelMessage.java
```

Is it proper to categorize it so that both uni test suites are enclosed by an AllSuites file? Such that

```
AllSuites
- LoginSuite
- MessageSuite
```

If making sub-Suites and putting them within Suites is proper, how would I do this? I currently have my login suite that looks like the following:

```java
package myPackages.loginSuite;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ 
    forgotPassTest.class, 
    loginTest.class, 
    registerNewUserTest.class })
public class LoginSuite {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have kept **LoginSuite** in **myPackages.loginSuite** package/folder, **MessageSuite** in **myPackages.messageSuite** package and **AllSuites** in **myPackages.allSuites** package. Then, your **AllSuites** code should be as shown below:

```
package myPackages.AllSuites;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

import myPackages.messageSuite.MessageSuite;
import myPackages.loginSuite.LoginSuite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({LoginSuite.class, MessageSuite.class})


public class AllSuite {
}
```

In the above code, as the suite classes (**LoginSuite** and **MessageSuite**) have different locations, following import statements have been added:

```
import myPackages.messageSuite.MessageSuite;
import myPackages.loginSuite.LoginSuite;
```

Comment: Would it be improper to put them in a folder? How would I call them within the folder though (o had issues properly importing them in another location of the directory as im not familiar with java as much)

Comment: It is not improper to put them in package/folder. It may not be necessary to create a separate package  (for example: *myPackages.loginSuite**) for each suite class, as it might result in too many packages. However, if you want to put suites or test classes in separate packages, you just need to put appropriate import statements in your class. I have modified my previous answer, please refer to it and let me know if you have any further queries.